# Why is a result element of type ParseResults if a component parser has a result name?

Tags: python, pyparsing

It is unclear to me why the parse results list sometimes contain ParseResults elements instead of strings.

For example:

```
from pyparsing import *

text = "pfx01ABC"

# nested result name
pfx = Literal("pfx")("prefix")
combined = Combine(pfx + Word(alphanums))("combined")

combined.runTests(text)
res = combined.parseString(text)
print("type(res[0]):", type(res[0]))
print('type(res["combined"]):', type(res["combined"]))

# doubly nested result names
infix = Word(nums)("infix")
pfx = Combine(Literal("pfx") + infix)("prefix")
combined = Combine(pfx + Word(alphas))("combined")

combined.runTests(text)
res = combined.parseString(text)
print("type(res[0]):", type(res[0]))
print('type(res["combined"]):', type(res["combined"]))
print('type(res["combined"]["prefix"]):', type(res["combined"]["prefix"]))

# no nested result names
pfx = Literal("pfx") + Word(nums)
combined = Combine(pfx + Word(alphas))("combined")

combined.runTests(text)
res = combined.parseString(text)
print("type(res[0]):", type(res[0]))
print('type(res["combined"]):', type(res["combined"]))
```

produces

```
pfx01ABC
[['pfx01ABC']]
- combined: ['pfx01ABC']
  - prefix: 'pfx'

type(res[0]): <class 'pyparsing.ParseResults'>
type(res["combined"]): <class 'pyparsing.ParseResults'>

pfx01ABC
[['pfx01ABC']]
- combined: ['pfx01ABC']
  - prefix: ['pfx01']
    - infix: '01'

type(res[0]): <class 'pyparsing.ParseResults'>
type(res["combined"]): <class 'pyparsing.ParseResults'>
type(res["combined"]["prefix"]): <class 'pyparsing.ParseResults'>

pfx01ABC
['pfx01ABC']
- combined: 'pfx01ABC'

type(res[0]): <class 'str'>
type(res["combined"]): <class 'str'>
```

Is it because result names are stored together with the nested parser and not globally?

In the case of doubly nested result names the result has the same number of enclosing square brackets as in the case of a single nested result name. Assuming the above, my expectation is a result with an additional set of enclosing square brackets. Why is this not the case?